# Why is Actual Revenue field wrong?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, sales

I've created an opportunity report using the Actual Revenue object, but the accounting department noticed that the amounts shown are consistently wrong by varying amounts.  Where does that field get its data from?  How do I correct this?

Comment: Are you using multi-currencies and do you have historic exchange rates?

Comment: Phil W, No I am not using multi-currencies or historic exchange rates.  This custom field was created by the previous SF admin. Turns out this field's formula isn't filtered to exclude expense items which are not counted as revenue.